# Can not integrate TeleStax Restcomm in MetaSwitch Clearwater

Tags: sip, telephony, restcomm, mobicents

I really want to study how restcomm works in clearwater as a Telephony Application Server.
I follow the guideline at:
http://telestax.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/ClearWater-RestComm-Integration-2013.pdf

But seemly, the verion of Restcomm in this article is too old (TelScale-Restcomm-JBoss-AS7-7.1.2-GA), and I am using the Restcomm in newer version (Restcomm-JBoss-AS7-7.7.0.900).
I could not follow the guide in this article because of some difference configuration between two versions.

I set up the clearwater successfully. I could make a SIP call in clearwater.
When I setup the restcomm (version Restcomm-JBoss-AS7-7.7.0.900),
I changed the local-address of media-server in file: standalone/deployments/restcomm.war/WEB-INF/conf/restcomm.xml
as follow:

```
<media-server-manager>
    ...
    <local-address>192.168.0.117</local-address>             
    ...
</media-server-manager>
```

(192.168.0.117 is my local IP address)

I did not change the references to 127.0.0.1:8080 in restcomm.xml file to point to 192.168.0.117:8180
because there is no references to 127.0.0.1:8080.
I think that may be the difference between two versions.
I also did not edit the JAVA_OPTS in bin/standalone.conf file because of misunderstanding.

I edit the file  mediaserver/deploy/server-beans.xml as follow:

```
<property name="bindAddress">192.168.0.117</property>
<property name="localBindAddress">127.0.0.1</property>
<property name="externalAddress"><null/></property>
<property name="localNetwork">192.168.0.0</property>
<property name="localSubnet">255.255.255.0</property>
```

After that, I start media-server:

```
$ cd ${JBOSS_HOME}/mediaserver/bin
$ ./run.sh
```

The media-server start successfully.

Then, I start restcomm jboss:

```
$ cd ${JBOSS_HOME}/bin
$ sudo ./standalone.sh -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=100 -b 192.168.0.117
```

It got errors as the below picture.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYtxl.png)

But Jboss server still work, when I goto http:/192.168.0.117:8180

But I can not access the Restcomm managerment interface.

I also try to modify somes as the article:

-Modify default app: standalone/deployments/restcomm.war/demos/hello-play.xml

```
<Response>
    <Play>http://192.168.0.117:8180/restcomm/audio/demo-prompt.wav</Play>
</Response>
```

-Add configure IMS core through Ellis configure file:

```
{
"Restcomm" :
"<InitialFilterCriteria><Priority>1</Priority><TriggerPoint> <ConditionTypeCNF></ConditionTypeCNF><SPT><ConditionNegated>0</ConditionNegated><Group>0</Group><Method>INVITE</Method><Extension></Extension></SPT></TriggerPoint><ApplicationServer><ServerName>sip:192.168.0.117:5180</ServerName><DefaultHandling>0</DefaultHandling></ApplicationServer></InitialFilterCriteria>"
}
```

-Bind the number to defaul app:

```
curl -X POST    http://ACae6e420f425248d6a26948c17a9e2acf:77f8c12cc7b8f8423e5c38b035249166@192.168.0.117:8180/restcomm/2012-04-24/Accounts/ACae6e420f425248d6a26948c17a9e2acf/IncomingPhoneNumbers.json -d "PhoneNumber=4321" -d "VoiceUrl=http://192.168.0.117:8180/restcomm/demos/hello-play.xml"
```

It got the error:

That are my problems.
Thank you very much for supporting me.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Indeed those steps are way too old and won't probably work on the new version.

I would recommend starting [Restcomm with Docker](http://docs.telestax.com/restcomm-docker-quick-start-guide/) instead and configure the JVM options and port offset (see http://docs.telestax.com/restcomm-docker-environment-variables/) in the docker run command

The rest of the description to configure Clearwater should still be valid.

Comment: Thank you Jeand for supporting me. I will try with docker.